# C# running InvokeMember in thread

Tags: c#, assemblies

so what i am tryng to do is to run the InvokeMember in a thread. Got the info here how to do it: [C# : Invoke a method with [Type].InvokeMember() in a separate Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505523/c-invoke-a-method-with-type-invokemember-in-a-separate-thread)

So my code looks like this right now and this works:

```
            Assembly OCA = Assembly.LoadFrom("./CardMax2.Elkart.OrderClutchAgent.dll");
            Type[] types = OCA.GetTypes();
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                //MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods();
                if (type.Name == "OrderClutchAgent")
                {
                    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    type.InvokeMember("RunAgent",BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null,obj,null);
                }

            }
```

Now when i try to run it in a thread, the code looks like this:

```
            Assembly OCA = Assembly.LoadFrom("./CardMax2.Elkart.OrderClutchAgent.dll");
            Type[] types = OCA.GetTypes();
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                //MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods();
                if (type.Name == "OrderClutchAgent")
                {
                    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
                                              {
                                                  type.InvokeMember("RunAgent", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, null);
                                              });
                    t.Start();
                }

            }
```

But with this code i am getting strange exception:

```
Method 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.TbsCertificateList+RevokedCertificatesEnumeration+RevokedCertificatesEnumerator.RunAgent' not found.
```

Am i doing something totally wrong or maybe someone can point out why i am getting this exception..

Comment: perhaps you could call the entire block of code on your second thread instead of that single method call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the legendary `foreach` capture issue - by the time it gets around to invoking it (on a different thread), the `type` variable refers to a different `Type`...

Make a copy instead:

```
foreach (var tmp in types)
{
    var type = tmp;
    // your code
}
```

The difference is that the loop variable (`type` in your example, `tmp` in mine) is scoped *outside* the loop (according to the spec), hence for capture purposes it is a **single variable** common to the entire loop. However, `type` in my example is scoped *inside* the loop, so (for capture purposes) is treated as a different variable per iteration.