# How do invoke AddPath()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, function, invoke

I have the following function:

```
 public void AddPath(String full_path)
    {
        TreeView tree_view = TheTreeView;
        String[] split_path;
        TreeNodeCollection current_nodes;

        if (tree_view == null)
            return;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(full_path))
            return;

        split_path = full_path.Split(tree_view.PathSeparator.ToCharArray());
        current_nodes = tree_view.Nodes;

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < split_path.Length; i++)
        {
            TreeNode[] found_nodes = current_nodes.Find(split_path[i], false);

            if (found_nodes.Length > 0)
            {
                current_nodes = found_nodes.First().Nodes;
            }
            else
            {
                TreeNode node;

                node = new TreeNode();
                node.Name = split_path[i]; // name is the same thing as key
                node.Text = split_path[i];

                current_nodes.Add(node);
                current_nodes = node.Nodes;
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to call this function from a seperate thread. How would I do this?
I know how how to invoke TreeView.Nodes.Add() but how would I do this? 0.o

-Swen

Comment: is this what you need?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505523/c-sharp-invoke-a-method-with-type-invokemember-in-a-separate-thread

Answer (score 1):

If you need to invoke some object in the UI from a thread different from the one that created it ( that is your case ) the answer is that you actually cant. A better answer is that you can by calling in winform [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx), and in WPF [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx). Only in winform you can investigate if calling invoke is actually required, by using [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx). In general you should well separate the asynchronous part from the part updating the UI in order  to avoid messing too much the code.